# Python mysql.connector use a variable in sql statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I need to be able to use a variable in an sql statement in order to search multiple different columns.

```
chicken = str("fav1")

cursor.execute("select %s from users where usersID=%s", (chicken, userID,))
favourite_exist = str(cursor.fetchone()[0])
print(favourite_exist)
```

While this statement doesn't produce any errors it is fetching the name of the column rather than the data associated with fav1 and userID = 389.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd add an additional step, i.e., `sql = "select {} from users where usersID=%s".format(chicken)` then `cursor.execute(sql, (userID,))`.

Comment: if you check with `print(cur._last_executed)` you will see the actual sql query will have quotes around your column name and hence always column name is returned.

Output of print statement `select 'fav1'  from users where usersID='389'`.

So as @JustinEzequiel suggested first prepare the query with column and then execute with parameters

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a go at this tomorrow.